# save JSON in HTML list item

Tags: javascript, html, json, list

I have a javascript where I can create list items in HTML. At the moment I can drag and remove the items with another script. Now I would like to store some information within every list item created, for an example a `JSON`-object. Then afterwards I save the data in the right order in the database.

Is it possible, or should I go another way?

Answer (score 1):

As Nikhita says you can add values as data-values attributes to the list items. For example if you want to store the id and name atributes you can do as follow, and recover the values with jquery:

```
<li data-id="1" data-name="name" class="listItemClick"> List item </li>;
$(".listItemClick").click(function(){
     var id=  $(this).attr("data-id");
     var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    //TODO

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

@Javier's answer works if you are using jQuery.

Those attributes can be accessed through regular Javascript as well.

```
// Make sure you have a valid reference
var el = getElementBySomeMeans();

// Set the value
el.setAttribute("data-test-this", "10");

// Get the value
var v = el.getAttribute("data-test-this");
console.log(v);

// Clear the attribute
el.removeAttribute("data-test-this");
```

I should mention, for completeness, that there is an HTML5 `dataset` method that also works on the data attributes, but I personally don't use it since we have to support older browsers at work.

IF you have the luxury, might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

1 - save data in html in any hidden div 
2- add data in any unique attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
<li data-name="' + data-value + '"> List item </li>;
```

This should do the trick. Append whatever data value and data name you see fit.